# Remove/style black oval around the globe

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

How can I remove the black oval around the globe in matplotlib's basemap or change its colour?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15/2))
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='#000000', linewidth=0.1)
m.drawcountries(color='#000000', linewidth=0.1)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0',lake_color='#ffffff')
plt.savefig("filename.svg", figsize=(24,12))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: On Anaconda dsitribution ... I think with `conda install -c anaconda basemap `

Comment: Try `m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0)`. For changing colors, try `m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=1, color='red')`

Comment: I can increase the width but even setting `m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0)` leaves a thin boundary.

Comment: Cheat code: set the color to white. Use `m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0, color='white')`

Comment: Can you try `m.drawmapboundary(linestyle='none')`?

Comment: "drawmapboundary() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linestyle'"

Comment: Do you want to remove the lines around the countries on the map, or do you want to remove the black oval around the globe?

Comment: The black oval around the globe

Comment: @Sheldore A hack is below; if you are interested investigating further on why there are two polygons and how to uniquely identify the one that needs to be removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that solves this:

```
for poly in plt.gca().findobj(plt.Polygon):
    if not poly == m._mapboundarydrawn:
        poly.set_linewidth(0)
```

However, this is quite brittle, as there may be other polygons in the axes. Still someone may take this as a starting point to investigate further.